# "Safely Remove Media" icon with no media

Tags: windows-10, safely-remove-hardware

I don't have any external devices plugged in but I'm seeing the "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" icon in my taskbar:

[image: Screenshot of the taskbar with the icon in question and irrelevant icons removed]

How do I get rid of it without hiding it permanently so when I do plug in a media, it still shows it on the taskbar?

This appeared all of a sudden last week and remains even after a restart. It definitely wasn't there before this month's patch Tuesday updates two weeks ago, but I can't remember if appeared *immediately* after the updates. (Felt like it appeared a few days after.)

This is on a 2016 Surface Book with Windows 10 Pro (Version 1703 Build 15063.674) with the latest updates on the CBB branch.

---

This may be related to ["Safely Remove Hardware" icon in Windows 8](https://superuser.com/q/501360/312890) but I also have a "..." underneath the icon and the highest-voted answer posted there didn't help since I don't have a USB 2.0 reader device:

[image]

Comment: " It definitely wasn't there before this month's patch Tuesday updates two weeks ago, but I can't remember if appeared immediately after the updates." - Have you removed those updates to see if the behavior still exhibits itself?

Comment: @Ramhound Nope but KB4041676 (the latest update) doesn't show up on the uninstallable updates list; only the security updates are there. Stability is much more important to me anyway (hence why I'm on CBB) and based on my previous [frustrating] experiences, I'd rather not use System Restore or uninstall updates unless I absolutely must. This is more of a minor annoyance that I was hoping someone already knew a quick answer for :/

Comment: You were only going to uninstall KB4041676 to see if the problem still existed.  After you confirm the update was the problem you could then decide if you wanted to install it again or not.  KB4041676 should be one of the updates you can uninstall.  My only other advice is upgrade to 1709 but I am guessing you are going to wait to do that.